# How can complicated user controls be drawn on C++?

Tags: c++, user-interface, cross-platform

Frameworks like Qt and GTK+ offer to developers some standard user controls like editboxes, comboboxes, etc. But many GUI-applications have more complicated user controls. For example, text editors have areas where user can input text and insert images or tables. Audio editors usually display waveforms of audiotracks, volume indicators, etc. My question is how such controls are drawn? Moreover, these controls usually can handle events - for example, tables in text editors can be selected, on right mouse button click some context menu pops up, etc. So, problem is not only to draw these controls, but also to make controls handle events. I have only idea to use Canvas or OpenGL, but I suspect that it would be difficult to implement events handling. May be, there are more simple ways to draw user interface?

Comment: That's why they are **frameworks** and not text editors or mp3 players. They provide building blocks for sophisticated GUIs. If you need some special display you create custom widget.

Comment: Seems overly broad to me -- enough material to fill a number of books.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty vague question, so this will be a somewhat vague answer. In general, most of this work has already been done. For example, Qt already has a text view class, an image class, and a table class (I'm not very experienced with Qt, just going from general stuff I know). For the text editor you are talking about, you might derive a class from a Qt text editing widget which has a handler to accept the dragging of images and can draw them. Again, Qt already has the code to draw images and do all kinds of painting.

To draw an audio waveform, you would have some sort of box or widget (generally speaking) that would draw a vertical line for each sampling interval to represent the volume or amplitude there.

Yes, OpenGL would be overkill for what you are talking about here because you would need to somehow write your own event handling, whereas most GUI frameworks do that for you. Again, a rather vague answer for a vague question, but I hope it helps!